# DOB validation in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to validate date of birth in Angular 2+ reactive form. I want to show error message when the selected DOB date is more than 100 years old.

**Front end side**

```
 <div [ngClass]="setClassDOB()">
 <input class="form-control" type="date"name="dob"formControlName="dob" placeholder="DOB">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your .html file :
And now design the form below the above div tag (in.html file): Try this one:

```
<input type="date" formControlName="dateOfBirth" />
<div *ngIf="form.get('dateOfBirth').errors?.invalidDateOfBirth">
  Please enter a valid date of birth (minimum age is 18).
</div>
```

In your .ts file:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';


export class MyComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      dateOfBirth: ['', validateDateOfBirth],
    });
  }


function validateDateOfBirth(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
  const dateOfBirth = control.value;
  const age = calculateAge(dateOfBirth);

  // check if date is valid and person is at least 18 years old
  if (isNaN(dateOfBirth.getTime()) || age < 18) {
    return { 'invalidDateOfBirth': true };
  }

  return null;
}

 function calculateAge(birthday: Date) {
  const ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
  const ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
  return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
 }
}
```

Try this out.

Comment: For more details, Refer to this link: https://kitcodes.blogspot.com/2023/06/validating-date-of-birth-in-angular.html

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Typescripting

```
  validateDOB(e){
    let year = new Date(e).getFullYear();
    let today = new Date().getFullYear();
    if(today - year >= 100){
      //Code Something
    }
  }
```

Update this in your html

```
<input class="form-control" (change)="validateDOB(dob)" type="date" name="dob" formControlName="dob" placeholder="DOB">
```

This may help you :)

Comment: `  validateDOB(e){
    let year = new Date(e).getFullYear();
    let today = new Date().getFullYear();
    if(today - year >= 100){
      return { 'has-danger': !this.dob.pristine && !this.dob.valid};
    }
  }` I have done this but not working

Comment: can u share your codings?

Comment: not working , for one thing the year lets you type numbers forever    - sure it says "code something"  but that should be part of the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom form validator to achieve that

1. Create a custom validator that takes a maxAge and returns a validatorFn

```javascript
const youngerThanValidator = (maxAge: number): ValidatorFn => control =>
  (new Date()).getFullYear() - (new Date(control.value)).getFullYear() > maxAge 
    ? { younger: { maxAge } } 
    : null;
```

2. Use it in you reactive form

```javascript
form = new FormGroup({
  dob: new FormControl(null, youngerThanValidator(100))
});
```

3. Display the error in your template when the input has been touched and is invalid

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="date" formControlName="dob">
  <span *ngIf="form.get('dob').touched && form.get('dob').getError('younger') as error">
    Too old : {{ error.maxAge }}
  </span>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked on first value set, but then control.value was always null